# Пагинация на wp

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет
У меня есть архив записей с пагинацией, на сайте 12 записей, и 5 страниц пагинации. Пагинация работает, но только до 3 страницы, начиная с 4 страницы я получаю 404 ошибку. В чём может быть проблема?

Мой код

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'post', // Your post type name
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        echo get_the_title() . '</br>';

    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Comment: @KAGGDesign попробовал использовать код из этого сайта, ситуация та же, после 3 страницы 404 отдает